# PHP Downloadpage headers prepend underscore to file name

Tags: php, download, http-headers, filenames, attachment

I have a script, where users can download created images. The relevant code is:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fooBarBaz.jpg"');
readfile($file); // path to file xyz.jpg
exit();
```

The download works as expected, every things fine with the image. The odd thing however is the image name. It get's downloaded as `_fooBarBaz.jpg`.

Question: Where does that `_` come from and more importantly, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried with different browsers?

Comment: @fusion3k shame on me, I haven't. Firefox adds the `_`, Chrome doesn't. So I guess it's a browser thing then. Thanks (: